# Multiple UITableView with independent dataSource

Tags: ios, uitableview, datasource

[EDIT]
Ok I found the problem, I was just calling the bad connection request of my web service. So downloading a blog would erase the articles list content. Time for a break :p

#

I'm upgrading an old app which is a simple **RSS reader** with a list of articles and a list of blogs. Each of these is a `UITableView` with its own `UITableViewController`.

Both of them retrieve data from a JSON file on my server.

At the end of the `JSON` parsing I update the `dataSources` and then call the `reloadData` method on both tableviews. The problem is that the articles list is filled with the blogs and the blog list isn't filled at all.

If I don't call `reloadData` on the blog `tableview`, the article one is filled correctly and works well. As seen on an other post I've tried with the `tableview.tag` identifier but it doesn't work.

Note: I'm not using `IB`.

Here is the code for the `BlogTableViewController`:

```
@implementation BlogsTVC
@synthesize dataSourceForBlogs;
@synthesize blogRec;
- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
    if ((self = [super initWithStyle:style])) {

        self.title = @"Blogs";
        self.tableView.tag = 2;
        self.tableView.delegate = self;

        dataSourceForBlogs = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

        // Register to notification
        [[NSNotificationCenter  defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(callback_blogs:) name:@"blogs" object:nil ];
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(connection_error:) name:@"connection_error" object:nil];        
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self refreshBlogs];
}

-(void)callback_blogs:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    if([self.dataSourceForBlogs count] > 0)
    {
        NSInteger i, count = [self.dataSourceForBlogs count];
        for(i=0; i < count; i++)
        {
            [[self.dataSourceForBlogs objectAtIndex:i] release];
        }

        [self.dataSourceForBlogs removeAllObjects];
    }

    //remplissage
    NSArray *receivedDatas = [[notification userInfo] objectForKey:@"data"];
    NSUInteger i, count = [receivedDatas count];
    for(i=0; i<count; i++)
    {
        self.blogRec = [[BlogRecord alloc] init];

        self.blogRec.blog_id_auteur = [[receivedDatas objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"id"];
        self.blogRec.blog_auteur = [[receivedDatas objectAtIndex:i]objectForKey:@"auteur"];
        self.blogRec.blog_url = [[receivedDatas objectAtIndex:i]objectForKey:@"url"];
        self.blogRec.blog_date = [[receivedDatas objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"date"];
        self.blogRec.blog_nb_pub = [[receivedDatas objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"nb_publication"];
        self.blogRec.blog_url_image = [[receivedDatas objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"theme"];

        [self.dataSourceForBlogs addObject:self.blogRec];
        self.blogRec = nil;
    }

    [self.tableView reloadData];

}
```

Here is the code for the Articles:

```
@implementation ActualiteTVC
@synthesize dataSource;
@synthesize artRec;
#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Initialization


- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style {
    // Override initWithStyle: if you create the controller programmatically and want to perform customization that is not appropriate for viewDidLoad.
    if ((self = [super initWithStyle:style])) {

        // Titles
        self.title = @"Actualités";
        self.tableView.tag = 1;
        // Register to notification
        [[NSNotificationCenter  defaultCenter] addObserver:self  selector:@selector(callback_general:) name:@"general" object:nil ];
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(connection_error:) name:@"connection_error" object:nil];

        self.dataSource = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    }
    return self;
}



#pragma mark -
#pragma mark View lifecycle


- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self refreshNews];
}

-(void)callback_general: (NSNotification *) notification
{   

    if ([self.dataSource count] > 0) {

        NSUInteger i, count = [self.dataSource count];
        for (i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            [[self.dataSource objectAtIndex:i] release];
        }

        [self.dataSource removeAllObjects];
    }

    NSArray *receivedDatas = [[notification userInfo] objectForKey:@"data"];
    NSUInteger i, count = [receivedDatas count];
    for (i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        self.artRec = [[ArticleRecord alloc] init];

        self.artRec.art_id = [[receivedDatas objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"id"];
        self.artRec.art_auteur = [[receivedDatas objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"auteur"];
        self.artRec.art_categorie = [[receivedDatas objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"categorie"];
        self.artRec.art_date = [[receivedDatas objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"date"];
        //self.artRec.art_texte = [[receivedDatas objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"texte"];
        self.artRec.art_titre = [[receivedDatas objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"titre"];
        self.artRec.art_url_auteur = [[receivedDatas objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"url_auteur"];
        self.artRec.art_url = [[receivedDatas objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"url"];
        self.artRec.art_url_img = [[receivedDatas objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"image"];

        [self.dataSource addObject:self.artRec];
        self.artRec = nil;
    }

    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

Finally here is how I add these TableViews in the TabBar:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

    // 0
        //articles
    ActualiteTVC *actualiteTVC = [[ActualiteTVC alloc] init];
    UINavigationController *actualiteNC = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:actualiteTVC];
    [actualiteTVC release];
    actualiteNC.tabBarItem.title = @"Actualités";
    actualiteNC.tabBarItem.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"08-chat.png"];
    [actualiteNC.navigationBar setBarStyle:UIBarStyleBlack];

    //1
    //blogs
    BlogsTVC *blogsTVC = [[BlogsTVC alloc] init];
    UINavigationController *blogsNC = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:blogsTVC];
    [blogsTVC release];
    blogsNC.tabBarItem.title = @"Blogs";
    blogsNC.tabBarItem.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"balance.png"];
    [blogsNC.navigationBar setBarStyle:UIBarStyleBlack];

    // myTabBarController
    myTabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
    [myTabBarController setViewControllers:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:actualiteNC,  blogsNC,  nil]];
    [actualiteNC release];
    [blogsNC release];


    /*
    //fullscreen
    CGRect frame = [[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame];
    frame.origin.x = 0;
    frame.origin.y = 25;

    //[baseViewCtrl.view setFrame:frame];
    [myTabBarController.view setFrame:frame];
    */

    /*
    // window
    //[window addSubview:myTabBarController.view];
     [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(handleRemoveLoading:) name:@"removeLoading" object:nil];
     loading = [[LoadingVC alloc] init];
     [window addSubview:loading.view];
     */

    [window addSubview:baseViewCtrl.view];

    [window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: is data there for both arrays(dataSourceForBlogs, dataSource)?.. check arrays before reloading table

Comment: It seems the "callback_blogs" method is never called ! My mind is blown

Comment: Check that "callback_blogs"  notification, means first add observer needs to load first, then you need to post notification

Comment: and check add observer name:@"blogs" and post notification name:@"blogs" is same or not

Comment: The observer is loaded before the download starts. And the notification names are the same

Comment: Something's weird: if I comment the reloadData in callback_blogs the articles list works fine. Else it shows the blog list instead. But if I do a NSLog before the reload it doesn't write anything in the console. Seems that the method isn't called but the tableView reloads the data.